# Динамический роутинг без params

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть такой роутинг:

```
resources :controller, olny: :index, path: 'dir' do
  get '*path' => 'controller#index', on: :collection, format: false
end
```

В `*path` попадает относительный путь в определенной директории, которая находится на фс ext4.
Если в имени директории попадается знак вопроса, то в `path` попадает все что до него, а остальное - в `params`. Хотелось бы что-то вроде этого:

```
get '*path' => 'controller#index', on: :collection, format: false, params: false
```

Знаю, что надо копать в сторону `constraints:`, но никак не допру, как их использовать.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Никак.

В URL знак вопроса `?` разделяет две существенно разных части URL:

```
схема://юзер:пароль@хост:порт/путь?строка_запроса
                                 ^ ^
```

Чтобы использовать `?` *как есть*, необходимо его **экранировать**.

В стандартной библиотеке Ruby есть `CGI.escape '?'`, и он выдаёт `"%3f"`. То есть, URL со знаком вопроса в пути будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
/name%3F/hi
```

Comment: Благодарю!
`path.gsub('?','%3f')` при генерации ссылок помогает.
В отличие кстати от `CGI.escape(path)` который вводит контроллер в заблуждение...

Comment: @Simant Разумеется, где `escape`, там и `unescape`. В `URI` что-то такое тоже есть, по-моему.

Comment: @Simant `path.gsub('?','%3f')` это ужасная идея. Кроме знаков вопроса есть много других символов, требующих экранирования .-.

Comment: Понимаю. Однако другие символы в url не мешают. Вероятно, рельса сама их экранирует. А вот знак вопроса - это прям камень преткновения...

Comment: @Simant могут быть сюрпризы далее :]

Comment: И где предложите ставить `unescape` если на строку после `escape` сам роутер ругается на невозможность найти маршрут?

Comment: @Simant смотря как формируете маршрут.

Comment: @Simant имелся в виду сам вызов хелпера.

Comment: Как описано в топике. После `escape` всего URL получается вот это: `No route matches [GET] "/%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0/404"`

Comment: @Simant в топике (а точнее, вопросе) **нет** вызова route-хелпера.

Comment: Я наверное еще слишком нуб и не знаю что такое route-хелперы.
Однако же, не вижу смысла усложнять процесс без явной необходимости. Кириллицу и прочий utf-8 рельса сама здорово экранирует, без `escape` адреса более читабельны в браузере, да и роутинг не требует лишних операций на входе...

Comment: @Simant рельса никакого UTF-8 не экранирует, просто браузер может спокойно переносить такие URL. А route-хелперы это как раз традиционный способ получать URL, основанный на маршрутах -- при аккуратных изменениях можно менять URL во всём приложении, меняя только `routes.rb`. Впрочем, может вы и правы, пока разберитесь с тем, что есть.